# Official Release Date of Appium GUI for iOS10

Tags: appium-ios

Can anybody tell me the official release date of Appium GUI to support iOS 10 version. In iOS 9 i used to identify the locators through appium inspector option under appium GUI which is now not working in iOS 10.

Or some body give me the work around to detect the object ids in iOS 10 till the Appium GUI for iOS 10 is officially released.

Answer (score 0):

**To install appium server 1.6 and to setup dependencies to be able to write tests for iOS10, you can follow this blog post:**

https://hasaanali.wordpress.com/2016/12/01/install-appium-v1-6-from-terminal-setup-for-ios/

**And to use Inspector with this:**

If you have downloaded/installed appium server using npm then you will launch it by running "$ appium" command from terminal.

After starting appium server from terminal, open older graphical appium (install it first if you don't have it already). Don't press Launch button from gui. Press apple button and add capabilities there (platform version, device name etc) and press Inspector button.

[image]

So the trick is to launch server from terminal and then use Inspector from same older graphical appium.